# How to make JAXB to annotate and provide equlas/hash code implementation

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I am trying to use JAXB to generate classes from WSDL which are annotated with Jsr303Annotations and provide implementation of equals and hashcode.

Both of these work separately, however when i try to achieve both requirements then i get error:

*An internal error occurred during: "Building workspace".
com.sun.tools.xjc.Plugin: Provider org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons.plugin.fixjaxb1058.FixJAXB1058Plugin could not be instantiated: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jvnet/jaxb2_commons/reflection/util/Accessor*

Could somebody tell me how to configure JAXB to do both of these ?

Bellow is my attempt to do so:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-wsdl</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
                            <schemaIncludes>
                                <include>*.wsdl</include>
<!--                                <include>*.xsd</include> -->
                            </schemaIncludes>
<!--                            <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate> -->
                            <!-- <removeOldOutput>true</removeOldOutput> -->
                            <!-- <cleanPackageDirectories>true</cleanPackageDirectories> -->
                            <strict>true</strict>
                            <extension>true</extension>
                            <args>
                                <arg>-XJsr303Annotations</arg>
                                <arg>-Xannotate</arg>
                                <arg>-Xequals</arg>
                                <arg>-XhashCode</arg>
                            </args>
                            <plugins>
                                <plugin>
                                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                                <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
                                <version>0.6.3</version>
                                </plugin>
                                <plugin>
                                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                                    <version>0.9.4</version>
                                </plugin>
                                <plugin>
                                    <groupId>com.github.krasa</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>krasa-jaxb-tools</artifactId>
                                    <version>1.1</version>
                                </plugin>
                            </plugins>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Edit: Relevant dependencies i have tried to use:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.4</version>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>1.0.0</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->


<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId> -->
<!--        <artifactId>jaxb2-commons-lang</artifactId> -->
<!--        <version>2.3</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->
```

Only the combination of first dependency and plugin for equals/hash code yield result.

If i include the other 2 dependencies then i get missing artifact -id message for every dependency in project.

Plugins for annotations work without explicit dependencies, when used without equals/hashcode plugin and vice versa.

**Edit: Final solution in case anyone gets stuck on same issue**

So it was required to separate annotations and equals/hash code plugins into separate executions, this resolved all issues.

Comment: Care to explain why this is off topic ? As i am fairly new to maven, I didn't know that two executions are required for these plugins to work nor it is an information i could google.

Comment: I've just solved our problem

Comment: could you add an answer with how you separated the executions of the two plugins. I am also running into the same problem and I am having trouble seperating it into two different executions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution. This plugin requires another one dependency:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.12.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>                             
        <generatePackage>com.argonio.fias.entity</generatePackage>                       
        <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/xsd</schemaDirectory>
        <readOnly>true</readOnly>
        <removeOldOutput>true</removeOldOutput>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <extension>true</extension>
        <args>
            <arg>-no-header</arg>
            <arg>-Xxew</arg>
            <arg>-Xxew:instantiate lazy</arg>
            <arg>-Xxew:plural</arg>
            <arg>-Xequals</arg>
        </args>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.jaxb-xew-plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-xew-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.4</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- This dependency is required to execute the plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-tools</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this dependency. By the way, your version 0.6.3 seems low.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-commons-lang</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I will try this later and let you know

Comment: Try version 0.9.4 as all your other jaxb2 dependencies.

Comment: i have tried version 1.0.0 and 1.0.1, there is no version 0.9.4 for annotations: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons/jaxb2-basics-annotate

Comment: so i have fixed issue with proxy, and updated all plugins and added that dependency. Still no luck with that :(

Answer (score 0):

The answer of @Viacheslav is correct. Note however that you also need to add a dependency for the project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.4</version> <!-- same as jaxb2-basics plugin version -->
</dependency>
```

See http://confluence.highsource.org/display/J2B/JAXB2+Basics+Plugins for all details.